# Is there a single word for 'Problem explanation and solution'

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single English word which covers "problem explanation and its solution'

I am going to use this as:

> Result: xyz[link-to xyz file] (which contains both problem explanation
>   and its solution).

Any kind of word (noun/verb etc) is acceptable.

Comment: Remediation or rectification can be considered.

Comment: 'which [adequately] addresses the problem'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OD online thesaurus gives as synonyms for "resolution"...

- solution to, answer to, end to, explanation to
- resolving, settlement, settling, solving, sorting out, working out, rectification, unravelling, disentanglement, clarification, conclusion, ending

I therefore propose "resolution".

Answer (score 0):

In education, it's called a *worked example*. The problem is presented together with the solution.

> "A **worked example** is a step-by-step demonstration of how to perform a task or how to solve a problem" (Clark, Nguyen, Sweller, 2006, p. 190). Worked-examples are designed to support initial acquisition of cognitive skills through introducing a formulated problem, solution steps and the final solution (Renkl, 2005).
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worked-example_effect#Worked_example)

Here is an instance of the term used in a dictionary example (emphasis, mine):

> **example** *noun*
>   1.1 A written problem or exercise designed to illustrate a rule.
>   ‘a workbook and a data set will enable the researcher to follow **worked examples**’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/example)